# Is using integer ids as string keys in cloud datastore a good idea?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to move an SQL database to cloud datastore. The sql database uses integer ids while datastore uses string key names. I know there is a way to allocate ids and stuff, but there is no need for this with string key names. So I could simply convert the integer id to a string and use that as key name:

```
key('Entity', '342353425')
```

Is there some problem with this approach? I  guess it's still provides good lookup performance if app engine asks for string key names.

Answer (score 1):

Key names are allocated so as to be random and evenly distributed. If you are using your custom IDs you must be sure that those are not monotonically increasing values, as 
 pointed before, it can lead directly to Datastore latency.

This document has the best practices for Datastore and specifically describes the best practices regarding [Keys Best Practices on Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/cloud-datastore-best-practices#keys)

> "If an application generates large traffic, such sequential numbering could lead to hotspots that impact Datastore latency. To avoid the issue of sequential numeric IDs, obtain numeric IDs from the allocateIds() method. The allocateIds() method generates well-distributed sequences of numeric IDs."

Answer (score 0):

By default, datastore gives each entity an integer ID.  You have the option to specify a string name instead of this integer ID or to specify your own integer ID.

If you specify your own string name or integer ID, then it can harm the ability of your app to scale to a large number of entities.

Essentially, the scaling of datastore requires that names or IDs be distributed across a range and not be sequential, clustered, and probably other things I'm not aware of.

If your SQL IDs are sequential then your app won't scale well.  If the SQL IDs look random, then it should be ok.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? The Entity docs mention string names first and just after it automatically generated ids and there is no mention of scaling issues: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#kinds_and_identifiers

Comment: @Tom, I don't believe it is documented well, and it is something I picked up over many years for reading Stack Overflow.  Try searching for "hot tablet" to get helpful info.